When use two argument or more with where get error
In ORM prisma when using AND, OR in the where clause get error:
PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid prisma.order.update() invocation in
→ 1146 const order = await prisma.order.update({
where: {
           AND: [
             {
               id: 456789
             },
             {
               orderStatus: 3
             }
           ],

Argument where of type OrderWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of idPK or id arguments. Available options are marked with ?.
This is my code:
    const order = await prisma.order.update({
  where: {
    // id: orderId,
    AND: [{ id: orderId }, { orderStatus: 3 }],
  },
  data: {
    orderStatus: 5,
    reason,
  },
});

Is it work for all or there is issue in the prisma itself ?

The error ocure cause the Ambiguity in where the update operation must target a single record. When combining AND with OR could match multiple records so get error
to solve this I get the origin data and apply condition on it after that update the data
